# Merge dataframes, different lengths

Tags: r, merge

I want to add variables from `dat2`:

```
          concreteness familiarity typicality
amoeba            3.60        1.30       1.71
bacterium         3.82        3.48       2.13
leech             5.71        1.83       4.50
```

To `dat1`:

```
    ID  variable value
1    1    amoeba     0
2    2    amoeba     0
3    3    amoeba    NA
251  1 bacterium     0
252  2 bacterium     0
253  3 bacterium     0
501  1     leech     1
502  2     leech     1
503  3     leech     0
```

Giving the following output:

```
    X ID  variable value concreteness familiarity typicality
1   1  1    amoeba     0         3.60        1.30       1.71
2   2  2    amoeba     0         3.60        1.30       1.71
3   3  3    amoeba    NA         3.60        1.30       1.71
4 251  1 bacterium     0         3.82        3.48       2.13
5 252  2 bacterium     0         3.82        3.48       2.13
6 253  3 bacterium     0         3.82        3.48       2.13
7 501  1     leech     1         5.71        1.83       4.50
8 502  2     leech     1         5.71        1.83       4.50
9 503  3     leech     0         5.71        1.83       4.50
```

As you can see the info from `dat1` has to be replicated over several rows in `dat2`.

This was my failed attempt:

```
dat3 <- merge(dat1, dat2, by=intersect(dat1$variable(dat1), dat2$row.names(dat2)))
```

Givng the following error:

```
Error in as.vector(y) : attempt to apply non-function
```

Please find replicate examples here:

dat1:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("amoeba", "bacterium", 
"leech", "centipede", "lizard", "tapeworm", "head lice", "maggot", 
"ant", "moth", "mosquito", "earthworm", "caterpillar", "scorpion", 
"snail", "spider", "grasshopper", "dust mite", "tarantula", "termite", 
"bat", "wasp", "silkworm"), class = "factor"), value = c(0L, 
0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("ID", "variable", 
"value"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 501L, 502L, 
503L), class = "data.frame")
```

dat2:

```
structure(list(concreteness = c(3.6, 3.82, 5.71), familiarity = c(1.3, 
3.48, 1.83), typicality = c(1.71, 2.13, 4.5)), .Names = c("concreteness", 
"familiarity", "typicality"), row.names = c("amoeba", "bacterium", 
"leech"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could add a join variable to dat2 then using merge:

```
dat2$variable <- rownames(dat2)
merge(dat1, dat2)
   variable ID value concreteness familiarity typicality
1    amoeba  1     0         3.60        1.30       1.71
2    amoeba  2     0         3.60        1.30       1.71
3    amoeba  3    NA         3.60        1.30       1.71
4 bacterium  1     0         3.82        3.48       2.13
5 bacterium  2     0         3.82        3.48       2.13
6 bacterium  3     0         3.82        3.48       2.13
7     leech  1     1         5.71        1.83       4.50
8     leech  2     1         5.71        1.83       4.50
9     leech  3     0         5.71        1.83       4.50
```

Comment: This answer works with the sample data shown but would drop all unmatched rows in `dat1` if there were any.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
merge(dat1, dat2, by.x = 2, by.y = 0, all.x = TRUE)
```

This assumes that if there are any rows in `dat1` that are unmatched then the `dat2` columns in the result should be filled with `NA` and if there are unmatched values in `dat2` then they are disregarded.  For example:

```
dat2a <- dat2
rownames(2a)[3] <- "elephant"
# the above still works:
merge(dat1, dat2a, by.x = 2, by.y = 0, all.x = TRUE)
```

The above is known as a **left join** in SQL and can be done like this in sqldf (ignore the warning):

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * 
         from dat1 left join dat2 
         on dat1.variable = dat2.row_names", 
       row.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 7):

Nothing wrong with @agstudy's answer, but you can do it without actually modifying dat2 by creating an anonymous temporary.  Adding X is similar:

```
> merge(cbind(dat1, X=rownames(dat1)), cbind(dat2, variable=rownames(dat2)))
   variable ID value   X concreteness familiarity typicality
1    amoeba  1     0   1         3.60        1.30       1.71
2    amoeba  2     0   2         3.60        1.30       1.71
3    amoeba  3    NA   3         3.60        1.30       1.71
4 bacterium  1     0 251         3.82        3.48       2.13
5 bacterium  2     0 252         3.82        3.48       2.13
6 bacterium  3     0 253         3.82        3.48       2.13
7     leech  1     1 501         5.71        1.83       4.50
8     leech  2     1 502         5.71        1.83       4.50
9     leech  3     0 503         5.71        1.83       4.50
```

Comment: Similar question.  I have multiple data frames which all are "per week" records.  I'd like to merge them all and plot them into one data frame.  How would I go about merging them?

Comment: @kiwicomb123 Here and in agstudy's answer, the key is to have a column with the same name in each data frame, which ties the results together.  `variable` already exists in `dat1` so it is added to `dat2` in order to do the merge.  `X` is added to `dat1` simply to match the output in the question.  (Note that there are no column names other than `variable` in common in the modified data frames here, so `merge` works with the default `by` argument.)