# How to merge panel data with macroeconomic data?

Tags: r, merge, stata, panel-data

I am trying to merge panel data from the Understanding Society Survey with macroeconomic data. The panel data from Understanding Society has :

- participant's ID number,
- year they were interviewed,
- country they were born in,
- life satisfaction score.

There are 10 observations per individual (followed over 10 years).

I am trying to merge this data with macroeconomic data which has 3 variables:

- GDP,
- year,
- country.

I want to merge these datasets by **year** and **country**. I made sure that the variables year and country were consistent between the two datasets. I thought that a `m:1 merge` in stata would do the trick, but I got the error :

```
variables year country do not uniquely identify observations in the using data.
```

I want my panel data to include the GDP of each individual's birth country in the specific year they were interviewed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, could you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge multiple data.frames in R with varying row length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023262/merge-multiple-data-frames-in-r-with-varying-row-length)

Comment: In Stata `duplicates list year country` is one way to follow up the report.