# Plotting text labels from one dataframe along a time-series with a higher frequency R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a time series of surface contacts (in `df1`) made by a person, as well as the temperature in the room (measured every few seconds and stored in `df2`). I'd like to plot `temperature` over `Dev.Date.Time` and below the y-axis (or in a facet plot), the `Surface` they touched with respect to `Dev.Date.Time`. The problem I have is that temperature is recorded every ten seconds whereas the movements happen more often.

```
head(df1)
  ActivityID CareType HCWType Orientation    Surface       Date     Time       Dev.Date.Time SurfaceCategories
1         01       IV    RN01  leftFacing AlcOutside 2019-08-03 11:08:01 2019-08-03 11:08:01       HygieneArea
2         01       IV    RN01  leftFacing         In 2019-08-03 11:08:12 2019-08-03 11:08:12                In
3         01       IV    RN01  leftFacing       Door 2019-08-03 11:08:12 2019-08-03 11:08:12        FarPatient
4         01       IV    RN01  leftFacing       Door 2019-08-03 11:08:18 2019-08-03 11:08:18        FarPatient
5         01       IV    RN01  leftFacing      Other 2019-08-03 11:08:22 2019-08-03 11:08:22        FarPatient
6         01       IV    RN01  leftFacing      Table 2019-08-03 11:10:26 2019-08-03 11:10:26       NearPatient

df2<-data.frame(sample(32:35,100,replace=T),Dev.Date.Time=seq(
     from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0","%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
     to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-3 23", "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
     by="10 seconds")
   )
```

I can plot the temperature but can't work out how to plot a string of characters over time. Any thoughts are much appreciated!

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Dev.Date.Time, y=Temperature)) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_text()
```

EDIT:

using:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Dev.Date.Time, y=Temperature)) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_text(data=df1, aes(label=Surface))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Dev.Date.Time, y=Temperature, label=Surface)) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_text()
```

You can also add `check_overlap = TRUE` to `geom_text` so that your labels don't overlap.

EDIT:

If you have two data frames with same variables, it should be enough to do the following:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Dev.Date.Time, y=Temperature)) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_text(data=df1, aes(label=Surface))
```

If your `df1` is missing temperature, create a dummy `Temperature` variable. If you want to show the labels a bit above `x-axis`, set the `Temperature` to `min` of `df2$Temperature`.

```
df1$Temperature <- min(df2$Temperature)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had forgotten I had measured the temperature at a faster rate than the movements so they are two different data frames. I apologise for this.

Comment: The new edit isn't working for me saying Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Surface' not found. So even if I create a dummy variable in df2 called Surface, it still doesn't show the labels. I'm trying instead to merge the data frames: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102498/merge-dataframes-different-lengths. I'll post an update if this works. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: oh, my bad. i've edited my edit to fix that. i've just flipped the data frames.

Comment: It still gives the same errors even if I switch them around, hmmm.

Comment: That's weird. Check your data frames. This works for me: `df2<-data.frame(Temperature=sample(32:35,208,replace=T),Dev.Date.Time=seq(
  from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0","%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
  to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 23", "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
  by="400 sec")
)` `df1<-data.frame(Temperature=sample(32:35,83,replace=T),Dev.Date.Time=seq(
  from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0","%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
  to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 23", "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
  by="1000 sec"), Surface="test"
)`

Comment: `ggplot(df2, aes(x=Dev.Date.Time, y=Temperature)) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_text(data=df1, aes(label=Surface))`

Comment: This works as predicted. Hmmm. So it looks like you have Temperature in both data frames. One of the temperatures could be dummy though I guess? The other slight nuance is that I'd like to write those labels just above or below the x axis. OR even in a graph parallel to the bottom of the y axis. What do you think?

Comment: There must be something up with my data frames... but I can't see what yet.

Comment: Oh, ok - I've just realised I was to quick for my own good and just assumed you have `Temperature` in both data frames. In that case, you can def add a dummy temperature in `df1`. If you want the labels to be just above the `x-axis`, set them to a value that's slightly below the `min` of `df2$Temperature`. My edit is above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will work out why the timezones in my dframes are making the plots at different times and how to make the labels vertical, this should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Dev.Date.Time, y = Temperature)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Surface))
```

check `?geom_text` for other arguments

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had forgotten I had measured the temperature at a faster rate than the movements so they are two different data frames. I apologise for this.